# VBA Add Worksheet from active Workbook to new Excel Application Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I try to copy the worksheet ("Pivot") from one Workbook to a new one.

```
        Private Sub button_start_Click()     'Start button in user form
        
        Dim app As New Excel.Application
        app.Visible = True
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Set wb = app.Workbooks.Add(input)    'import some Data via user form. This works.
        
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pivot").Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)  


        End Sub
```

The last line is not working. I am not sure if the workbook relation between the two workbooks is clear defined.

Can someone help?

Best regards

Comment: What does "not working" actually mean?

Comment: Why do you need a separate instance of Excel?

Comment: I need to change/correct some of the "input" Data. The correct Data is in the "Pivot". In the end the new excel should include the correct data, without directly overwriting the old one. This is why I want to copy the incorrect and correct data in a new workbook in two worksheets.

Comment: Ok, but why do you need a *new* instance of Excel to do this? What is the need for `app`? Why not just `Set wb = Workbooks.Add(input)`?

Comment: Thats a good question.  Thanks for that hint, thats helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

1. The word input is a reserved word.
2. You can still use your method of declaring a new app although not necessary.
3. Two methods.
   This first one works but it is not efficient and is pretty ugly.

   ```
   Private Sub button_start_Click()     'Start button in user form
   Dim app As New Excel.Application 
   Dim wb As Workbook
   Dim sourceWb As Workbook
   Dim wbFullName as String, wbName as String

    app.Visible = True
    'Change the textbox1 to what ever is the relevant to your
    'situation (I assumed the value given is for an existing workbook and path)

    Set wb = app.Workbooks.Add(TextBox1)
    wb.save '(saveas) 
    wbFullName = wb.FullName
    wbName = wb.Name
    wb.close 'The Workbooks collection doesn't register the newly opened book
             'using this new app method .. So close it and reopen it 
    set wb = Workbooks.Open filename:=wbFullName
    sourceWb.activate 'Make the source workbook active

    sourceWB.Sheets("Pivot").Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
   End Sub
   ```

OR

You can do it this way

```
  Private Sub button_start_Click()     'Start button in user form
   Dim app As New Excel.Application
   Dim wb As Workbook
   Dim sourceWb As Workbook
    app.Visible = True        
    Set sourceWb = ThisWorkbook
    'Change the textbox1 to what ever is the relevant to your
    'situation (I assumed the value given is for an existing workbook and path

    Set wb = Workbooks.Add(TextBox1)
    sourceWb.Activate
    sourceWb.Sheets("Blank").Copy After:=Workbooks(wb.Name).Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
  End Sub
```